# TimedRotatingFileHandler not able to rename file when file rotation is happening

Tags: python, logging

I am writing logs by running a same microservices on 10 different ports. When I run the microservice (uses flask app) on all ports for the first time, all 10 instances of microservice are able to write logs in the same log file.
However, after some time when `TimedRotatingFileHandler` changes the log file, I get this error.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 74, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 404, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 115, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: --------------------------
---------------------
Call stack:
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\threading.py", line 930, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 84, in handler_thread
    task.service()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py", line 397, in service
    task.service()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 168, in service
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 434, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\johndoe\.conda\envs\xyz\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File 
-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
```

This error is coming because one of the service instance has started writing logs in log file but `TimedRotatingFileHandler`  can not rename the file since it is in use. I also observed that one of the instances also wrote log in old backup file. but other 8 instances can not write logs.

My logging code:

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
app_logger = logging.getLogger('app_logger')
app_logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
log_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(app_log_path,when='S', interval=300, backupCount=1)
log_handler.setFormatter("some_format")
app_logger.addHandler(log_handler)
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the same file from multiple processes without running into problems. You will need to either use a `SocketHandler` and a suitable socket server or a `QueueHandler` / `QueueListener` (as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) in the official docs). The code for these approaches is too big to post here, but the linked page shows working code for a socket server.